# Compute new variables and use those variables to compute other variables

Tags: r

With the following data in two columns, I am trying to compute new variables, which I then want to use to compute other variables. The two variables I have are "Area" and "Observed"

```
Area         Observed
3353        31
2297        2
1590        15
1087        16
817         2
847         10
1014        28
872         29
1026        29
1215        21
```

I need to compute a new variable called "Relative area" by summing "area" and dividing each "area" value by the total. For Example 3353/14118 = 0.237

I then need to compute a new variable called "Expected" by summing "Observed" column and multiplying each value by the newly computed "RelativeArea".

The error I get is: Column "Expected" must be length 10 (the number of rows) or one, not 0

The next column needs to be computed as "O-E" which is the "Observed" column minus the "Expected" (newly computed column). Of course, I can't get to this because of the above error.

I have been able to generate the first new variable "RelativeArea", but cannot create the next one "Expected"

The code I used:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- read.csv("data1.csv")
data %>% mutate(RelativeArea = data$Area/sum(data$Area)) ##this works
data %>% mutate(Expected = data$RelativeArea*sum(data$Observed)) ##this DOES NOT WORK and gives me the error: Column "Expected" must be length 10 (the number of rows) or one, not 0
```

I would expect that the "Expected" column uses the values from the "RelativeArea" column and multiplies each value with the SUM of the "Observed" values  to compute the "Expected' value....

Comment: You don't need `data$` within `mutate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `data$`, and create each variable in mutate, separated with a comma:

```
data <- read.csv("data1.csv")

data %>% mutate(RelativeArea = Area/sum(Area), 
    Expected = RelativeArea*sum(Observed)) #close the mutate
```

#### Explanation

You don't need to call `data$` repeatedly, that is why you are not getting the result you want. When you call `data$` it is mutating from the data, as it appeared in the original data frame that you sent to the first `mutate`. But after creating the first variable, you have created a new data frame implicitly, which has different variables. Separate the next variable mutation by a comma, and make your next variable in the same call.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers, I first separated the second mutate "Expected" from the first one, as you initially suggested - but the error message I got was Object "RelativeArea" not found. When I tried your second method "Separate the next variable mutation by a comma, and make your next variable in the same call:" I got an error message: Error: unexpected ',' in data %>% mutate(RelativeArea = Area/sum(Area),(Expected = 
   RelativeArea*sum(Observed))"

Comment: @GaiusWilson there is a typo, delete the first `(` before "Expected"

Comment: Wow! That worked, thank you very much. Question though - why does the error message say: unexpected ',' in data%.....instead of unexpected "(" in....?

Comment: This depends on the structure of your data, which I can't really help you with unless you post some of your data. `Tidyverse` functions are very adaptable and arguments can take many different forms to aid in this flexibility. What results is a "black-box" method in which the behaviors and error messages can sometimes be unexpected if you don't know exactly what you're doing. Useful resource: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Very much appreciate your help. The data that I was using is in my initial question, just not sure why it is not displaying it as a table: The two columns are Area" and "Observed" Area Observed 3353 31 2297 2 1590 15 1087 16 817 2 847 10 1014 28 872 29 1026 29 1215 21.